# json.loads change " " to single quote

Tags: python, json

I am writing a program to call an API. I am trying to convert my data payload into json. Thus, I am using json.loads() to achieve this.

However, I have encountered the following problem.

I set my variable as following:

```
apiVar = [
     "https://some.url.net/api/call", #url
     '{"payload1":"email@user.net", "payload2":"stringPayload"}',#payload
     {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "text/plain"}#headers
]
```

Then I tried to convert apiVar[1] value into json object.

```
jsonObj = json.loads(apiVar[1])
```

However, instead of giving me output like the following:

```
{"payload1":"email@user.net", "payload2":"stringPayload"}
```

It gives me this instead:

```
{'payload1':'email@user.net', 'payload2':'stringPayload'}
```

I know for sure that this is not a valid json format. What I would like to know is, why does this happen? I try searching a solution for it but am not able to find anything on it. All code examples suggest it should have given me the double quote instead.

How should I fix it so that it will give the double quote output?

Comment: JSON and python dict are not same, convert to JSON

Comment: `json.loads` returns an ordinary Python `dict` value; JSON isn't involved anymore. The type of quotes used to *display* that `dict` are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did follow through with json.dumps() and changed my variable slightly and able to make the API call. If no one points this, I'd probably be stuck for a time I am not able to afford to lose so this helps is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.loads()` takes a JSON string and converts it into the equivalent Python datastructure, which in this case is a dict containing strings. And Python strings display in single quotes by default.

If you want to convert a Python datastructure to JSON, use `json.dumps()`, which will return a string. Or if you're outputting straight to a file, use `json.dump()`.

In any case, your payload is already valid JSON, so the only reason to load it is if you want to make changes to it before calling the API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the json.dumps to convert the object back into json format.

The string with single quotes that you are reverencing is probably a **str**() or **repr**() method that is simply used to visualize the data as a python object (dictionary) not a json object. try taking a look at this:

```
print(type(jsonObj))
print(str(jsonObj))
print(json.dumps(jsonObj))
```